# org.json.JSONException: No value

Tags: android, json

org.json.JSONException: No value in array

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {

            try {
                questionsList = new ArrayList<QuestionsBean>();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray question = jsonObject.getJSONArray("questions");
                for (int i = 0; i < question.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject x = question.getJSONObject(i);
                    QuestionsBean u = new QuestionsBean();
                    u.setDate(x.getString("date"));
                    u.setQuestion(x.getString("question_text"));
                    JSONObject bject = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray answers = bject.getJSONArray("answers");
                    for (int j = 0; j < answers.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject xx = answers.getJSONObject(i);
                        u.setAnswer_body(xx.getString("Answer_body"));
                    }
                    questionsList.add(u);
```

Comment: That means your `answers` array will be `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling `getJSONArray` on the correct `JSONObject`. Use

```
JSONArray answers = x.getJSONArray("answers");
```

Also, since your `JSONArray` could be null, use [`optJSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray(java.lang.String)) to avoid the exception and check if it's null before continuing.

Something like

```
JSONArray answers = x.optJSONArray("answers");
if (answers != null) {
  // for loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject bject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray answers = bject.getJSONArray("answers");
```

You constructed here an empty JSONObject, so it is normal what it cannot find 'answers' in it.